# Python 3.7 command line issues in Windows 10

Tags: python-3.x, cmd, windows-10, git-bash

Trying to use the  `MkVirtualEnv` command in a directory outside the main python directory.

I am using [windows-10](/questions/tagged/windows-10) and [python-3x](/questions/tagged/python-3x), *(3.7)*. I have installed it twice and selected the option to add it to %PATH%. I've also gone into Control Panel to check that the directory was added to %PATH%.

For some reason python commands like `pip install` and `--version` only work in [cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd) if I'm in the `\Python` directory, they do work in [git-bash](/questions/tagged/git-bash). In either CLI after installing `VirtualEnvWrapper` the `MkVirtualEnv` command won't work unless I'm in the `\Python` directory.

I'm confused as to what I'm missing.

Comment: Did you `activate` your virtualenv? See https://medium.com/the-andela-way/configuring-python-environment-with-virtualenvwrapper-8745c2895745 Also, questions with no code usually go to https://superuser.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a `Scripts` folder in the installation directory of python. That is where `pip` is. If you want to access it from anywhere, the path to the Scripts directory also needs to be added to windows `PATH` along with the path to `python.exe`.